# Is there any way to center tile text on the start menu on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have Windows 10. It's good OS but tiles on the start menu make me sad.

Tiles text is left aligned. I want it to be in center. Is there any way to center the tile title on the start menu?

I've mocked up what would be ideal here:

[image]

Comment: Open Windows Feedback and suggest them this option.

Answer (score 0):

NO, its not possible at the moment. Tiles are represented by an XML file with links to the apps. Windows just reads this XML, but you can't change the read behavior.